# $L^2$decomposition

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, malliavin-calculus

I want to know following statment's proof.
Let $L^2:=\{F:\textrm{wiener function} |\int_W F(\omega)^2 P(d\omega)<\infty \}$,and
$C_0:=\{\textrm{constant}\},C_n:=P^n \cap \{C_0\oplus...\oplus C_{n-1} \}^{\perp}$ where $P^n$ is polynomial which degree is at most $n$.
Then $L^2=\oplus_n C_n$

This is content of page.354 in [Stochastic Differntial Equation and Diffusion Processes] written by N.IKEDA and S.WATANABE.
Thank you very much for your kind support.

Comment: In the definiton of $L^2$ I suspect you are missing a square on the $F$. This is the so called "Wiener chaos decomposition", a very complete treatment can be found in Svante Janson's book "Gaussian Hilbert spaces".

Comment: the result you look for is in chapter II

Comment: Thank you for pointing out.  I revised.
And,I appreciate for showing book.
I will try to read it. Thank you.